# API cannot connect to company page

Tags: linkedin-api

We have software running where users can post on their personal timeline as well on their company pages (administrator). Over 400 users use this feature on a daily base. Works perfect.

However...

There is 1 users that only can post on his personal timeline and not on his company page.

This is the API log response when we try to retrieve the listed company pages:

*Viewer don't have permission to the ADMIN_ONLY VisibilityReduction for urn:li:organization:5xxxxx*

We already verified that this user is an administrator for this company page.

**Question:**

Since the other administrator (for the same company page) can successfully post on this company page we can rule out that there is an issue with the company page itself. It rather seems some kind of a setting for this particular person.

Someone an idea what this setting might be?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?